# PHP copy specific words from text file and append them to a specific row

Tags: php

I have a `PHP` that does some text manipulation saving the user input and gets this unix timestamps and also saves them on a text file and in the end the file looks like this:

```
1;0%;5%;4;1527085890;
1;15%;0%;1;1527085890;
1;20%;0%;2;1527085890;
2;5%;2%;3;1527085901;
2;20%;0%;1;1527085901;
2;2%;0%;2;1527085901;
3;2%;0%;5;1527085912;
3;20%;0%;1;1527085912;
3;3%;0%;2;1527085912;
```

Basically on the first three rows the timestamp in the end is the same, on the next three rows the timestamp in the end is the same etc. What I would like to get in the end of every line is to copy the second timestamp and append it to the first three rows, get the third timestamp and append it to the next three rows and so on. Finally to get this output:

```
 1;0%;5%;4;1527085890;1527085901;
 1;15%;0%;1;1527085890;1527085901;
 1;20%;0%;2;1527085890;1527085901;
 2;5%;2%;3;1527085901;1527085912;
 2;20%;0%;1;1527085901;1527085912;
 2;2%;0%;2;1527085901;1527085912;
 3;2%;0%;5;1527085912;
 3;20%;0%;1;1527085912;
 3;3%;0%;2;1527085912;
```

[EDITED] PHP: //on the sample output I have shortened some things

```
$t=time();
$myfile1 = fopen("temp/time.txt", "w");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    fwrite($myfile1, $t.";\n");
}

    $ranks = fopen("temp/ranks.txt", "w");
    $selected_val = $_POST['rank1'].";\n".$_POST['rank2'].";\n".$_POST['rank3'].";\n".$_POST['rank4'].";\n".$_POST['rank5'].";\n".$_POST['rank6'].";";
    fwrite($ranks, $selected_val);

    $ranks_array = file("temp/ranks.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $time_array = file("temp/time.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $first_page_array = file("temp/userID.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $second_page_array = file("data/data1.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $final_array = [];

    foreach($first_page_array as $key=>$first_page){
       $final_array[] = $first_page.''.$second_page_array[$key].''.$ranks_array[$key].''.$time_array[$key]."\n";
    }

    file_put_contents('output.txt',$final_array, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Does your code write to the file adding the text after each operation? Or is the text saved in a buffer that is written all at once?

Comment: @Yeti82 After each operation it adds to the file.

Comment: This is definitely do-able using PHP. Where exactly are you running into trouble?

Comment: Can you add the code that writes in your file to your question? It may be useful to know how the string is composed and how it is written to the file. The solution can be different based on these factors. I explain, depending on how the file is written and how the string is composed you can try to add the information you need before writing the string in the file. What you need is a support variable in which to hold the information before writing it.

Comment: @Yeti82 Yes, sorry I edited it. Completely forgot ;(

Comment: @Rulli I updated my answer to to include how my code works with reading an writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us much information; however, I'll give this a go.

I assume that you have already written your text file into a string and cleaned it up (trim). We'll start from there.

```
1;0%;5%;4;1527085890;
1;15%;0%;1;1527085890;
1;20%;0%;2;1527085890;
2;5%;2%;3;1527085901;
2;20%;0%;1;1527085901;
2;2%;0%;2;1527085901;
3;2%;0%;5;1527085912;
3;20%;0%;1;1527085912;
3;3%;0%;2;1527085912;
```

First, break your working string into a working array, around your line-break character: `$working = explode("\n",$workingString);` (assuming a line-break called "\n")

Second, walk through the new array and break it into subarrays:

```
foreach($working as $values){
    $subvalues = explode(";",$values);
    $elements[] = $subvalues;
}
```

You could probably do this in a single step. I am breaking it into two for explication.

Now you should have an array that looks like this:

```
array $elements = 
 [0] => array [0] => 1
              [1] => 0%
              [2] => 5%
              [3] => 4
              [4] => 1527085890
 [1] => array [0] => 1
              [1] => 15%
              [2] => 0%
              [3] => 1
              [4] => 1527085890
 [2] => array [0] => 1
              [1] => 20%
              [2] => 0%
              [3] => 2
              [4] => 1527085890
 [3] => array [0] => 2
              [1] => 5%
              [2] => 2%
              [3] => 3
              [4] => 1527085901
 [4] => array [0] => 2
              [1] => 20%
              [2] => 0%
              [3] => 1
              [4] => 1527085901
 [5] => array [0] => 2
              [1] => 2%
              [2] => 0%
              [3] => 2
              [4] => 1527085901
 [6] => array [0] => 3
              [1] => 2%
              [2] => 0%
              [3] => 5
              [4] => 1527085912
```

Next, walk through this new array to get an array of the unique timestamps:

```
foreach($elements as $value){
    if(!in_array($value[4],$uniqueTimestamps)){
        $uniqueTimestamps[] = $value[4]
    }
```

See where I'm going with this?

Your final walkthrough will add the second timestamp to any subarray which is missing it:

```
foreach($elements as $key => $value){
    if(count($value) < 6){ // because you will only ever have 5 or 6 values
        $k = $array_search($value,$uniqueTimestamps);
        $k = $k + 1; // i.e. $k++... again, I'm writing this long-hand
        // adding 1 to $k gives you the next timestamp in the unique array
        $elements[$key][] = $uniqueTimestamps[$k];
    }
}
```

To finish, walk through your $elements array and implode everything back to a $finalString, then overwrite that to your file.

I didn't test the code. Let me know if you have any troubles.

Comment: @Rulli Smith Whatever comes of this, let me know. Where I am, it is the start of the weekend in 5... 4...  but I will follow up on this, as I am won't to do for such things. Enjoy the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to capture the different parts of the string and build it in one loop.
The regex will capture the first three items as one group then the following as one each.

```
Preg_match_all("/(.*?;.*?;.*?;.*?;)(.*?);(.*?)/", $str, $matches);
Foreach($matches[1] as $key => $match){
    If(isset($matches[2][$key+3])){
        $temp = $matches[2][$key+3] . ";";
    }Else{
        $temp = "";
    }
    $res[] = $matches[1][$key] . $matches[2][$key] . ";" . $temp;
}
Echo implode(PHP_EOL, $res);
```

https://3v4l.org/Nrq15
It also works if you append the file with more items later.
https://3v4l.org/s1NKS

Edit I see that you have edited your question to include more code.
This method should be used with file_get_contents and not fopen since it requires the full string in one item not as an array.
That also means it does far fewer loops than a fopen and explode method.